# Apache beam Python: condition and break

Tags: python, apache-beam

I've search a lot about this but not any useful information.

Is is possible to build a pipeline with `if` condition? And at some conditions, break the pipeline?

I can implement this partly by using `with_outputs` and making multiple branches. But if I want to run different pipeline based on the input arguments, all branches got executed and all create output files even some branches have empty input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a sample pipeline that incorporates various conditionals.

**Here's the code functionality in brief:**

1. Create `parser` (input) arguments, mainly input and output file destinations from a Google Bucket. One argument will be a boolean.
2. Create pipeline arguments, such as specifying `--runner` and `temp` & `staging` locations.
3. Set up pipeline options.
4. Contents in the pipeline are only executed if the variable `run_pipeline` is `True`.
5. Based upon the input parameter `my_condition`, the file that is read from in the pipeline is determined.
6. The above file is written to a Google Bucket
7. A new `PCollection` is created, and only outputted if the input condition `my_condition` is `True`.

**Overall, this pipeline demonstrates:**

- Building a pipeline with an `if` condition
- At some conditions, the pipeline is broken
- Running parts of the pipeline based on an input parameter

**How to run the code:**

1. Copy and paste the code into a python file
2. Open the terminal in the location where the file is, and then type `python code_file_name.py`. You will need to edit the names of the buckets (to those of your own) before you run the code.

**Code:**

```
import argparse

#   import apache beam PTransforms
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromText
from apache_beam.io import WriteToText

from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions


def run(argv=None, save_main_session=True):
    """Main entry point."""

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()  # creates a parser

    # output & input destinations are from a Google Bucket
    parser.add_argument(  # add first output command & destination
        '--output_1',
        dest='output_1',
        default='gs://my-bucket/output_1',
        help='Output file to write results to.')
    parser.add_argument(  # add second output command & destination
        '--output_2',
        dest='output_2',
        default='gs://my-bucket/output_2',
        help='Output file (2) to write results to.')
    parser.add_argument(  # add first input command & destination
        '--input_1',
        dest='input_1',
        default='gs://my-bucket/input_1.txt',
        help='First input file to process')
    parser.add_argument(  # add second input command & destination
        '--input_2',
        dest='input_2',
        default='gs://my-bucket/input_2.txt',
        help='Second input file to process')
    parser.add_argument(  # add conditional command & destination
        '--my_condition',
        dest='my_condition',
        default=True,
        help='Condition for pipeline')

    # store our parser arguments in 'known_args'
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    # pipeline arguments are below:
    pipeline_args.extend([
        # --runner=DataflowRunner',  # you can run this with Dataflow, but it will take longer
        '--runner=DirectRunner',
        '--project=my-project',
        '--staging_location=gs://my-bucket/staging',
        '--temp_location=gs://my-bucket/temp',
        '--job_name=demo-job',
    ])

    # setting up pipeline options

    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = save_main_session

    # the pipeline
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:

        if run_pipeline:

            if known_args.my_condition:
                pipeline_read_file = known_args.input_1
            else:
                pipeline_read_file = known_args.input_2

            # PCollection containing contents of an input file, based on conditional
            pcoll = (
                p | beam.io.ReadFromText(pipeline_read_file)
            )

            # Write our PCollection to a Google Bucket
            pcoll | "Write PCollection To Bucket" >> beam.io.WriteToText(known_args.output_1, num_shards=1)

            # PCollection that will only be written based on an input condition
            pcoll_break_cond = (
                p | beam.Create([{"key": "value"}])
            )

            if known_args.my_condition:
                pcoll_break_cond | "Write Break Condition PCollection To Bucket" >> beam.io.WriteToText(known_args.output_2, num_shards=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_pipeline = True     # This variable determines if the pipeline is run at all
    run()
```

Comment: Hi Junming, if the above answer helped to clarify your question, I ask that you please accept and upvote the answer so that in the future others can see it too.

If there are some details you would like clarification on, let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for my late response and thank you for your answer. Very helpful